# Unique together between field and model connected by ForeignKey django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field, django-constraints

I have two models.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(choices=AttachmentChoices.get_choices(), max_length=15)
    link = models.URLField()
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='attachments')
```

I want to do something like this in meta class of Post model

```
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('title', 'attachments')]
```

but it dosn't work couse django can't find attachments field.
Is there a solution provided by django that can solve this problem.

Comment: You should use OneToOne field for this use-cases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: in my case there shoud be more then one attachment for every post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) and also try to create a many-to-many relationship between `Post` and `Attachment` models using `attachments` field, try the following:

```py
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField('Attachment', related_name='posts')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['title'], name='unique_title_with_attachments')
        ]
```

Now, [django](/questions/tagged/django) will create a unique constraint on the combination of `title` and `attachments` fields. This means that when you create a new `Post` instance, Django will check if there is already a `Post` instance with the same `title` and `attachments` combination, and if so, it will raise a `ValidationError`.